# Start local Phyton Script via HTML button

Tags: html, webserver, local

I have an apache webserver installed on my ubuntu client. The webserver is being accessed by clients from LAN.
I want to have a HTML button, which starts a locally saved phyton script (/etc/skript.py) on my ubuntu client.

I've tried different things, but nothing seemed to work.
What's the easiest way to do it?

Thanks for you help.

I tried this one out:

```
<button type="button" onclick="/etc/script.py">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of an `onclick` attribute needs to be the source code for the body of a JavaScript function.

Code running in web pages displayed in browsers have no way of executing files on the client.

You can use a link or submit a form to a URL handled by the HTTP server and then make [the HTTP server responsible for executing the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943107/how-do-i-use-python-as-a-server-side-language). This will run the script on the server, not the client (although they might be the same computer in your case… at least some of the time).

Answer (score -1):

As Quentin mentioned you can create a fastify server or express one, the below example is using fastify

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/kindly-bald-gong

Basically:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Execute Python Script</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="executeScript()">Execute Python Script</button>

  <script>
    function executeScript() {
      fetch('/execute-script')
        .then(response => {
          if (response.ok) {
            console.log('Python script executed successfully.');
          } else {
            console.error('Failed to execute Python script.');
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('An error occurred while executing the Python script:', error);
        });
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
fastify.get("/execute-script", function (request, reply) {
      exec("python ./src/scripts/skript.py", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error("Failed to execute Python script:", error);
          reply.code(500).send("Failed to execute Python script");
        } else {
          console.log("Python script executed successfully");
          reply.send("Python script executed successfully");
        }
      });
    });
```